# Storing dynamic number of data values on same row in SQL database table

Tags: c#, sql, database

I need to store test results from a device into a table in a SQL Database. An example of what data needs to be stored for each test could be:

> id, load units, height units, load, height

However other tests might look something like this:

> id, load units, height units, load1, height1, load2, height2, load3, height3...

One solution I thought of would be to set an arbitrary limit to how many possible load and height values it would be possible to store in the table. Which also means a number of load/height columns may be null depending on the test result. However, this seems like a messy solution.

Would it be more suitable to store multiple load/height values formatted in XML? Or is there any other possible solution?

Edit: I wouldn't need to be able to search for data using the load/height values, there will be other fields such as "Test Name" and "Timestamp" that will be used to search for data.

Comment: Would you need to search data on the fields `load1, height1, load2, height2, load3, height3.` eventually or you would always access these attributes at record level?

Comment: You want to read about [database normalization and normal forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).  Basically this case is what table relationships are designed for.

Comment: @Chandu I have edited the question in response to your comment.

Comment: (in particular, "one-to-many" relationships)

Comment: Having these *repeating* columns (like `load1`, `load2` etc.) violates even the **first normal form** of database design. You should learn the basics of good database design, and get comfortable with the normalization of relational databases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a table that contains the Test ID, Load Units and Height Units, one for the Load results (with TestID and LoadResult, for example), and another for Height results (TestID and HeightResult). No nulls required.

Comment: It seems like (load, height) results come in pairs, and therefore should be in a single "test iteration results" table, linked to the "tests" table by ID.  Another field might be needed if order of results should be preserved.

Comment: Fair point; at work, I'm always sending things back to the requirements writers for clarification before writing a character of code, perhaps I should adopt that attitude on here!

Comment: @BenVoigt That solution makes more sense to me. I will probably add in another field to preserve the order of the results. Thanks for the useful guidance!